# OpenCV filter2D and negative values

Tags: python, opencv

I'm implementing a simple Laplacian filter using OpenCV's filter2D function using the following code:

```
tempkernel = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,-4,1],[0,1,0]])
kernel = np.array(tempkernel,np.float32)
mylaplaceda = cv2.filter2D(blurred,-1,kernel)
cv2.imwrite("outimage.jpg",mylaplaceda);
```

"blurred" is the input image. Now, the output images seem look the same (when viewed as images) when compared with OpenCV's built-in Laplacian() function. But filter2D seems to trim negative values from the input image:

Max value using Laplacian(): 43

Max value using above: 43

Min value using Laplacian() : -55

Min value using above: 0

Is there any way to remedy this, or am I doing something wrong here? Even using the delta argument with a negative value subtracts from the max value, but the min value remains the same.

Comment: what datatype is your image? I guess 8UC3? OpenCV uses saturate_casts to omit under-/overflows. Try to convert your input image to CV_16SC3 type before applying your filter!

Comment: ah, yes that was it. `mylaplaceda = cv2.filter2D(blurred,ddepth=cv2.CV_16S,kernel=kernel)` works.